# Typescript: Pick keys from function argument

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function which first argument determines the keys of the result. Given only one key in the result, I can create a function like the following:

```typescript
type MyType = {
    green: string;
    red: string;
    blue: string;
}

async function fetchStuff<T extends keyof MyType>(properties: T): Promise<Pick<MyType, T>> {
    const result = await fetch("http://localhost", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "properties": properties
        })
    });
    
    return await result.json();
}

// Works fine
console.log(fetchStuff("green").then(x => x.green))

// Syntax error - as expected
console.log(fetchStuff("green").then(x => x.red))
```

Now I want to modify this function, so it can take a list of properties and return a object containing only the given keys. Modifying my code with something like

```typescript
async function fetchStuff<T extends Array<keyof MyType>>(properties: T): Promise<Pick<MyType, T>>
```

did not work, as the array is not compatible with 'keyof MyType'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, just return `Promise<Pick<MyType, T[number]>>` instead of `Promise<Pick<MyType, T>>`

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKuoHMAnCCAOwC4oBnYQgS1PwG5s8piATSm+xlnPACMANgFcI3Wg2bYAvtmwBDKiFIBjKADNR64HQD2pLRGBqAFgGVgozZoA88KBAAewMhypQAgoUKKQdgDWECD6mrAISAB8UQAUYIT6kIR6EFSU8ACUlAAKiQC2dFQQdjl0aoF2cIiQADRQ8ADapKL5ghCEALox6Kx4aoY07GmiwsBQqIoA7op045om5rEARGbAwGDkAPRbwvpqisJm+jTL9ZgCbLj5JsdcUMs5APIW8Gd9V1CC+hwglABSFieADkAHQ8aR0TQgWIXT6fZYJJIdVJUZaUJHJVEfK6yTI4vH8Ng44jWQhGaazcbEKijYCggBWVEMsUy-HkWGwOygAHV9IRAp5NAwINgBqRmcIIKC9vhYgtTJZrLZYo1lkQSKRlp1MqDgGYyLFnBMolBnKCNWRMvjOVhuRZVMBFMaOolCFAALRQZROZyQNRuDhiwb6KUy-RyhXmKw2TSq9XEMja3X6w3G5Cm82ca0KO1bXn8wVaEXBiWh6Wy+WLJWx+OWrX1ZacZN6g2kI0ms2g7M2rn5h2kJ0u3z8z3ezwuf2B0uSisRquKmMqtX1s4PZs61tpzvmkTia1AA)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate what adding `[number]` does, and why it works?